# beginner python: nested classes and loading data into them

Tags: python, class

I'm new to python web development (and OOP in general).  I have a view in my data base that consists of 7 "parts", and I wanted to divide them into their own classes (though the data is "joined" in my database). The parts/classes would be TrainerData, Pokemon1, Pokemon2, etc...

Here's a more simple version of what i'm going for.  I know the issue and error, I just don't have the knowledge to solve this one.  Here's what I have so far.

```
import psycopg2

class Trainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData()

    class TrainerData:
        def __init__(self, trainername, battle, winnings):
            self.trainername = trainername
            self.battle = battle
            self.winnings = winnings

        @classmethod
        def load_from_db_by_tname(cls, tname):
            with psycopg2._connect(user='postgres', password='samfurdissamrea', database='ODS', host='localhost') as connection:
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute('SELECT trainer_name, battle, winnings from public.poke_data_web WHERE lower(trainer_name) = lower(%s)', (tname,))
                    trainer_data = cursor.fetchone()
                    return cls(trainername=trainer_data[0], battle=trainer_data[1], winnings=trainer_data[2])


a = Trainer()
print(a.trainerdata.load_from_db_by_tname('angus'))
```

The error returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ageeray/Documents/Python Scripts/PokeTrainerWeb/trainer.py", line 22, in <module>
    a = Trainer()
  File "C:/Users/ageeray/Documents/Python Scripts/PokeTrainerWeb/trainer.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData()
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'trainername', 'battle', and 'winnings'
```

I can get this to work if I don't have the TrainerData as a nested class, but otherwise, I've hit a wall.  All input is appreciated; thank you for your time.

Comment: The code shown in the traceback does not match the code above it.  Please show us the code you're actually running and the error message it produces.

Comment: It should be `a = Trainer(Trainer.TrainerData.load_from_db_by_tname('angus'))`, but I find it rather strange that you use nested classes anyway, why is this useful here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem tbh, i'm not quite sure.  I just thought that this would be the logical way to organize my classes, but maybe i'm wrong.  I guess I could break out the nested classes into their own, non nested classes, but I wasn't sure how to make them "join"/ depend on one another.

Comment: No, nested classes are rarely useful in Python. Your classes here would work exactly the same, you just wouldn't refer to it with `self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your inner class `TrainerData` requires 3 arguments `trainername, battle, winnings` which you listed as arguments in class `__init__` function.

However, you are trying to create an object of `TrainerData` in the main class without any arguments

> self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData()

This actually triggered your problem. You need to provide 3 arguments for this nested class.

```
self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData('John', 'StackOverflow', +10)
```

**BTW** you can also specify default arguments for `__init__` function:

```
   class TrainerData:
        def __init__(self, trainername="nobady", battle="any", winnings=0):
            self.trainername = trainername
            self.battle = battle
            self.winnings = winnings
```

In this case, you actually can create an object of this class without arguments. It would set a default argument for any missed one. For example, all below would perfectly work in this case

```
self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData()
self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData(trainername="John")
self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData(trainername="John", battle="StackOverflow")
self.trainerdata = self.TrainerData(trainername="John", winnings=100)
```